# i want create curl with proxy find ip basic example in php

Tags: php, curl, proxy

i want to create a curl with proxy & find Ip of proxy Basic Example

I write a code belong follow

```
<?php
$proxy_ip = '76.27.149.203';
$proxy_port = '8080';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded","Accept: */*"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $proxy_port);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy_ip);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    $head = curl_exec($ch);
    var_dump($head);
    //var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to verify proxy or find proxy ?? `whatismyip.com` do not contain list of proxy

Comment: whatismyip.com is for the check the proxy is working or not this script return my current ip not proxy ip

Comment: And what is the question in this?

Comment: Your script works http://codepad.viper-7.com/VWMkCL .. what exactly is the issue

Comment: i want only curl request send with proxy

Comment: What are you trying to find the IP address of?  "curl request send with proxy" doesn't make much sense, in the context of the code you have posted.  Is your code not working for you?